# devise: multiple redirects for multiple sign up forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, routes

I have two sign up forms for devise, and I would like to redirect the user to two different pages upon registering depending on which sign up form they used. What is the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding into application_controller.rb:

```
  def after_sign_up_path_for(user)
    user.something? ? dashboard_path : root_path
  end
```

Not sure if this will work, but you can overwrite `Devise::RegistrationsController` if it won't.